# Database design -- what should be included in Order and not in Invoice and vise versa in a simple online store?

Tags: database, database-design, e-commerce

I'm developing a simple online store with simple functionality. Among others, there're 2 tables: Orders and Invoices.

**What exactly should be included in one and not in the other?** For now I can think of what they'll have in common: a reference to a product, quantity.

For instance, a reference to a shipping method along with the cost -- should this be included in Invoice or Order?

Answer (score 0):

We can't answer this without some further information about your business processes.

- Will an order sometimes only be partially filled? If so you may need to issue an invoice that is different to the order.
- Will you be shipping partially today, and the rest later when the goods arrive in your warehouse? If so, one to many invoices could link to the parent order.
- The day will come when you need to issue a refund for some reason. In many systems invoices also act as credit notes. How do you intend handling this?

So my take is that you are correct having separate invoices and orders tables, although an invoice will typically be generated from data held in the order table. Put simply, the order is what the customer wants; the invoice reflects your financial transaction. If you think along these lines it should become obvious what is required in  each table.